# Javascript - How to get the url for Youtube videos programmatically? (self-answer)

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

An extremely common question is "How do I get the url for a Youtube video?". Most answers involve some scraping and regexing the html of a video page or resort to 'use this 3rd party tool or website'.

Its extremely easy to do this from the dev tools console in any browser on any Youtube video page.

See the answer below.

Comment: Interesting concept with **self-answer** - didn't know it is possible to publish a question and answer it immediately to keep track of the knowledge...

Comment: @MichalStefanow yeah there's some documentation about it. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @MichalStefanow, I know right? Had to bookmark that link incase I need to pull out the "official" evidence one day (**if** such answers causes issues)...

Answer (score 3):

Example is here:

https://gist.github.com/geuis/8b1b2ea57d7f9a9ae22f80d4fbf5b97f

```
// Run from the dev tools console of any Youtube video
// Accurate as of June 12, 2016
var videoUrls = {};
ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(',').forEach(function (item) {
  var obj = {};

  item.split('&').forEach(function (param) {
    param = param.split('=');
    obj[param[0]] = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
  });

  videoUrls[obj.quality] = obj;
});

console.log(videoUrls);
```

Sample output for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0

```
{
  "hd720": {
    "url": "https://r3---sn-n4v7sn76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au&mv=m&mt=146577…zA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&ip=108.233.85.171&key=yt6&requiressl=yes&itag=22&cnr=14",
    "quality": "hd720",
    "s": "1BEF82C7D9487809555E4B5124CA244FD93857C62.7869EB3FE7E8BE955B85E19F769DD80C49F3A87CB",
    "itag": "22",
    "type": "video/mp4;+codecs=\"avc1.64001F,+mp4a.40.2\""
  },
  "medium": {
    "url": "https://r3---sn-n4v7sn76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au&mv=m&mt=146577…AxLnNqYzA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&ip=108.233.85.171&key=yt6&requiressl=yes&itag=18",
    "quality": "medium",
    "s": "35ADDCF2F151540B9AE72455ED9CD079B3A166669.F168091B130653FCACA72506C01625B74E46C1A7D",
    "itag": "18",
    "type": "video/mp4;+codecs=\"avc1.42001E,+mp4a.40.2\""
  },
  "small": {
    "url": "https://r3---sn-n4v7sn76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au&mv=m&mt=146577…AxLnNqYzA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&ip=108.233.85.171&key=yt6&requiressl=yes&itag=17",
    "quality": "small",
    "s": "0C397549D581241F0F39D3EB8BF6E9B9067F65AFD.76B46A360178C4B001E96166C46AEAE5CF0D6A35F",
    "itag": "17",
    "type": "video/3gpp;+codecs=\"mp4v.20.3,+mp4a.40.2\""
  }
}
```

Comment: How is any arbitrary language supposed to access a browser's Dev Tools? Imagine I need the Youtube URL for my app made with  C++ \ C# \ Java \ Swift \ Python \ PHP etc etc. `console.log` becomes irrelevant so that's why there's a need to regex / scrape the HTML page or involve some parsing tool.

Comment: @VC.One Your question is a valid one, but it isn't within the scope of this post. That's why I set the 'javascript' language tag. I've gone back and added dev tools tags also to make it clearer.

Comment: @VC.One You would need to use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) instead of the `get_video_info` end-point because it doesn't send a CORS response (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header).

Comment: @VC.One do you now which encoding for the file which is returned by http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=xxxx?